# How to record what tools I used to make image in GIMP?

Tags: code-generation, capture, gimp

I want to proceduraly generate textures made by GIMP. I know there is [GIMP library for Python](http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/pygimp/) which can call GIMP's tools with parameters. If I know what tools (with parameters) GIMP used then I should be able to reproduce image programatically (procedurally generate image). How to record what tools (with parameters) GIMP uses while I am drawing image?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to a GIMP equivalent of `Actions` in `Adobe Photoshop`. AFAIK, they are called [GIMP Scripts](http://osp.wikidot.com/gimp-scripts). 
[This is a starting point](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-script-fu-tutorial-first-script.html), if you are going to make your own Scripts

Comment: Yes, they are GIMP scripts. Thanks. :) Now I need to capture them.